# Formatting specific output from dmidecode

Tags: awk

I was searching for a means to format output from dmidecode a specific way, and I found the following article which just about does what I need

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/Shell/Q_27770556.html

I modified some of the fields that I need from the code in the answer above, this shows awk creating csv output, with quotes, from dmidecode

```
dmidecode -t 17 | awk -F: '/Size|Locator|Speed|Manufacturer|Serial Number|Part Number/{sub(/^ */,"",$2);s=sprintf("%s,\"%s\"",s,$2)}/^Memory/{print s;s=""}END{print s}' |sed -e 's/,//' | grep -iv "no module" | tr -d ' '

"4096MB","CPU0","DIMM01","1066MHz","Samsung","754C2C33","M393B5273CH0-YH9"
```

I need tabbed, no quotes

```
4096MB  CPU0    DIMM01  1066MHz         Samsung         754C2C33        M393B5273CH0-YH9
```

I am still trying to get my head around awk and would appreciate anyone showing me the appropriate modifications

Fixed my code above, previously pasted non-working syntax

Comment: I would settle for even just a space separating the fields, but my tweaking is failing to find the right modifications to the syntax above...

Comment: Could you post the output of `dmidecode -t 17` on your system?

Comment: The quick fix would to be change `s=sprintf("%s,\"%s\"",s,$2)` to `s=sprintf("%s\t%s",s,$2)`. But it's still ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you posted, I saved the data in a file called `file.txt`. I noticed that records are blank line separated. I used the following `awk` code:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; OFS="\t" } /Size|Locator|Speed|Manufacturer|Serial Number|Part Number/ { gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$2); line = (line ? line OFS : "") $2 } /^$/ { print line; line="" }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
2048 MB XMM1    Not Specified   1333 MHz    JEDEC ID    8106812F      HMT125U6BFR8C-H9
No Module Installed XMM2    Not Specified   Unknown JEDEC ID        
2048 MB XMM3    Not Specified   1333 MHz    JEDEC ID    7006C12F    HMT125U6BFR8C-H9
No Module Installed XMM4    Not Specified   Unknown JEDEC ID        
4096 kB SYSTEM ROM  Not Specified   Unknown Not Specified   Not Specified   Not Specified
```

Your command line would now look like this:

```
dmidecode -t 17 | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; OFS="\t" } /Size|Locator|Speed|Manufacturer|Serial Number|Part Number/ { gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$2); line = (line ? line OFS : "") $2 } /^$/ { print line; line="" }' | grep -iv "no module"
```

**EDIT:**

```
dmidecode -t 17 | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; OFS="\t" } /Size|Locator|Speed|Manufacturer|Serial Number|Part Number/ { if ($2 ~ /MB$|MHz$/) { gsub(/[ \t]+/,"",$2) } gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$2); line = (line ? line OFS : "") $2 } /^$/ { print line; line="" }' | grep -iv "no module"
```

Comment: Thank you steve, that very nearly does it, except the MB and MHz being separated from their values. I can fix that with sed after the fact, can we do it within the same awk command?

Comment: @user1629011: Glad that helped. A quick way to remove spaces separating the values would be to change `gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$2)` to `gsub(/[ \t]+/,"",$2)`. Note that this will impact all values on the line. Otherwise, please see my edit. I've added an `if` statement to correct only the MB and MHz separations. This may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there a more graceful way to get rid of the blank line that appears at the beginning of output other than adding `|sed '/^$/d'`?